# Ngrok streaming audio exception

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, ngrok

I've write a Client / Server code using Java server socket ( TCP ).
The server is working as a Radio, listening to Mic, and sending the bytes to connected clients.
When i run the code using "localhost" as server name, it works very well, and i can hear the voice in the speakers without any issues.

Now, when i want to expose the localhost to internet using ngrok:

```
Forwarding                    tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:11049 -> localhost:5000
```

I start to get below exception in the client side:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal request to write non-integral number of frames (1411 bytes, frameSize = 2 bytes)
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.write(Unknown Source)
    at client.Client.Start(Client.java:79)
    at client.Receiver.main(Receiver.java:17)
```

Does any one know why, and how i can fix such problem ?

I tried to change the byte array length.

//server code

```
byte _buffer[] = new byte[(int) (_mic.getFormat().getSampleRate() *0.4)];
 // byte _buffer[] = new byte[1024];
  _mic.start();
   while (_running) {
   // returns the length of data copied in buffer
   int count = _mic.read(_buffer, 0, _buffer.length);
   //if data is available
    if (count > 0) {
       server.SendToAll(_buffer, 0, count);
        }
      }
```

// client code where exception happens:

```
_streamIn = _server.getInputStream();

            _speaker.start();

            byte[] data = new byte[8000];
            System.out.println("Waiting for data...");

            while (_running) {
                //  checking if the data is available to speak
                if (_streamIn.available() <= 0)
                    continue;   //  data not available so continue back to start of loop

                //  count of the data bytes read
                int readCount= _streamIn.read(data, 0, data.length);
                if(readCount>0){
                    _speaker.write(data, 0, readCount); // here throws exception
                }
            }
```

should play the sound through the speaker.